# When does the community user review first posts?

Tags: support, review, new-users, community-user

I was going through some posts in Ask Ubuntu and found a post which was reviewed by the community user.

https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/1121292

Does the community user review first posts once in a blue moon or often?

Why is it reviewing posts when a normal user (having access to the review queue) can do it?